# How can i traverse 2 link list at the same time?

Tags: java, arrays, list, traversal

I know I can do a loop, but then how I get it to traverse 2 of them at same time??? Also, I have no idea the size of the list, so I cant use a for loop. Rather, a while loop is prob need to be used... Is it going to be a big boolean expression?

I will try what I can, thank for some ideas.

Comment: You should show what you've tried so people can help point you in the right direction. Also, if you ask a question on stack overflow you should accept answers that helped you to give credit where credit is due.

Comment: You need to describe what you want to do by traversing the two lists and post some code you have written so far

Comment: Using iterators this is easy to achieve.

Comment: And of course, you should go back and accept answers for some of your 6 questions.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. How can we use a Iterator to iterate two lists in parallel? As there would be only one iterator per list.

Comment: You definitely need to read [ask].

Comment: @RohitJain Using two iterators, naturally.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik.. Yeah I actually thought that. :)

Comment: Could your list be of different size?

Comment: I should read the rule... sorry. But there are answers that unable to help solve my problem... so :\

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how it's done with two iterators:

```
for (Iterator<String> it1 = list1.iterator(), it2 = list2.iterator(); 
     it1.hasNext() && it2.hasNext();) 
{
   final String s1 = it1.next(), s2 = it2.next();
   // stuff to do
}
```